# What is the status of development and future of the SE API?

Tags: support, api

While as a non developer, and whose code tends to consist of hastily hacked together bits of bash its not of direct use for me, I'd love to have the option of a android app again.

While the official application is depreciated - there's mentions of an API 2.3 it uses, and that non [availability of it was a blocker](https://stackapps.com/questions/8255/alternative-to-official-app#comment17204_8255) for a replacement- and that the [API was possibly never going to be released](https://stackapps.com/questions/8149/please-release-and-or-document-api-version-2-3)

For extra fun, [there's mentions of an API 3.0 coming](https://stackapps.com/questions/1999/announcing-api-version-1-1-and-roadmap) and api.stackoverflow.com referenced on some stackapps posts seems to 404 out.

While I should know better than to ask multiple questions, what is the status of development and the future of the SE/SO API, will there be future public releases, and is it in active development and use in any way? Would there be plans for things like teams to be exposed for developers to build their own bridges and/or apps?

If someone wanted to find the current API docs, what would be the right place, and what's the blockers for release of the 2.3 api?

Comment: Teams [does have API access](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4385859-stack-overflow-for-teams-api).

Comment: [The current SE API docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs). The [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/) home page also has a link for [registering an application](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) and [managing your applications](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth).